# Trying to take user input in plsql but not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

```
SET SEROUTPUT ON;  
accept designation char PROMPT 'enter designation' ;  
DECLARE      
    v_salary_inc number;  
      v_desg varchar2(20) := &designation;

BEGIN  
    v_salary_inc := case v_desg   
        when 'manager' then .3  
        when 'lead' then .18  
       when 'senior engg' then .1  
        else .05  
        end;  
        dbms_output.put_line('your salary increase is :' || v_salary_inc);         
END;
```

Error report -

```
ORA-06550: line 3, column 24:  
PLS-00201: identifier 'MANAGER' must be declared  
ORA-06550: line 3, column 12:  
PL/SQL: Item ignored  
ORA-06550: line 6, column 23:  
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or  
 malformed
```

Comment: You've just removed code from your question and is now asking for people to type it in manually.. that doesn't make any sense. Kindly put back your code, along with your error as code formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you did - by editing the question and adding an image instead of code - was wrong. Not everyone sees images. You'd rather post code.

Anyway: here's what went wrong with your code.

Use **help** if you aren't sure what to do. `accept` uses `char`, not `varchar2` and no size.

```
SQL> help accept

 ACCEPT
 ------

 Reads a line of input and stores it in a given substitution variable.

 ACC[EPT] variable [NUM[BER] | CHAR | DATE | BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE]
 [FOR[MAT] format] [DEF[AULT] default] [PROMPT text | NOPR[OMPT]] [HIDE]
```

As of code you wrote: you're missing single quotes in line #3. The rest seems to be OK (after you enable output, of course).

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> ACCEPT designation char PROMPT 'enter designation: ' ;
enter designation: lead
SQL> DECLARE
  2      v_salary_inc number;
  3      v_desg varchar2(20) := '&designation';
  4  BEGIN
  5   v_salary_inc := case v_desg
  6          when 'manager' then .3
  7          when 'lead' then .18
  8          when 'senior engg' then .1
  9          else .05
 10          end;
 11   dbms_output.put_line('your salary increase is :' || v_salary_inc);
 12  END;
 13  /
your salary increase is :,18

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: edited the code still not running .pls have a look.

Comment: Everything you need to know is contained in my answer. Please, have a look.